# XA0134: The application does not have the 'android:debuggable' attribute set in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Tags: xamarin

I'm getting this deployment error in my xamarin visual studio PROJECT, can anyone help me?
I'm getting this even if I have debuggable poperty in manifest or not.

Comment: just an idea: set the attribute "android:debuggable" and make a clean/rebuild of your project

Answer (score 2):

It's generally safer to set this using the Attribute via the Android file `AssemblyInfo.cs` rather than in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This way you can determine if you're actually debugging via `#if DEBUG` versus publishing your app with a `RELEASE` build.

Attribute sample (`Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`).

```cs
#if DEBUG
[assembly: Application(Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
                       Debuggable = true)]
#else
[assembly: Application(Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
                       Debuggable = false)]
#endif
```

However, if you want the `Properties\AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<application android:label="SampleApp" 
             android:debuggable="true" 
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
             ... />
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives an error: "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields, methods or statements"